# Rails 5: Nested routes without a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to add a specific nested route to my rails appilcation. I already added nested routes and others before, but never did something similar like this and I'm wondering if this is possible.

I would like to achieve this result in the end

```
get '/marketplace' => 'pages#marketplace'
get '/marketplace/airbnb' => 'marketplace#airbnb'
```

Now I have a PagesController where I have this action

```
def marketplace
end
```

And a view `marketplace.html.erb`

How can I append the airbnb route to the `marketplace` action ?

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/marketplace/airbnb' => 'pages#marketplace', :defaults => { :airbnb => true }
```

So the URL `/marketplace/airbnb` will use the `marketplace` action with `params['airbnb']` equal to true.  This is not foolproof, as someone could use your website with `/marketplace?airbnb=foobar` or `/marketplace/airbnb?airbnb=foobar` which would set `params['airbnb'] = 'foobar'`.